# How may I format my function for apply() to calculate specific columns?

Tags: r, function, apply

Beginner with R functions, TIA. I have a large dataset where I'd like to calculate values based on two different columns. I believe I should use `apply()` and write a function, but I'm unsure how to combine all these elements successfully.

I'm looking to calculate the sqrt() of one variable, x, divided by the sqrt() of x plus a different variable, y: `sqrt( as.numeric(x) ) / ( y + sqrt( as.numeric(x) ))`. My data frame `env.metadata` contains these variable values as columns where x is `env.metadata$gl_a` and y is `env.metadata$dist` and I'd like this computed value for each row. Dput() of example `env.metadata` below.

This is where I'm struggling: I want to use `apply(env.metadata, MARGIN = 1, my.fun)` where `my.fun` is the above equation. Could someone please help with this link?

Edit: typo

```
> dput(env.metadata)
structure(list(gl_a = c(244, 437, 130, 339), dist = c(45, 31, 
77, 104), other_cols = c(2, 3, 4, 5), another_col = c(6, 7, 8, 
9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vectorised calculation so you don't need `apply` -

```
sqrt( env.metadata$gl_a ) / ( env.metadata$dist + sqrt(env.metadata$gl_a ))
#[1] 0.2576769 0.4027498 0.1289766 0.1504098
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with `purrr::map2` we can get the same output

```r
library(purrr)

unlist(map2(df$gl_a,df$dist, \(x,y) sqrt(x) / (y + sqrt(x))))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
[1] 0.2576769 0.4027498 0.1289766 0.1504098
```